# How to validate the amount of input words after using split?

Tags: java

I'm trying to validate the input of only three words, so if the user enter less or more the program prompts the same question again.

How I'm doing the input of words? I'm using BufferedReader and splitting my String by every space (" ")... so every space means a new word.

But how can I control the amount of words to be typed?

I have coded this:

```
    InputStreamReader st = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(st);



    System.out.println("Enter 3 words");
    String words = bf.readLine();
    String split[] = words.split(" ");


    do
    {

        System.out.println("Enter only 3 words");
        words = bf.readLine();
        String split[] = words.split(" ");



    }while(split.length > 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `!=` comparator instead of `>` :

```
while(split.length != 3)
```

Also, you are overwriting your `split[]` array in your do-while loop. Do not create a new array, use the same variable you created earlier. This will also prevent multiple prompts from appearing should the correct number of words be entered the first time.

```
InputStreamReader st = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(st);

String words;
String[] split;

do
{
   System.out.println("Enter 3 words");
   words = bf.readLine();
   split = words.split(" ");

}while(split.length != 3);
```

Comment: When I move everything into my "do while", it says my variables cannot be found.

Comment: @Midori I wasn't suggesting moving everything to your do-while, but rather to replace the `String split[]` with a reference to your already created `split` var. I've edited my answer to remove a typo, it should be clearer now.

Comment: I see, however... it asks me twice to enter my words when I enter 3 words.

Comment: @Midori Check my edit, it should ensure the prompt only appears once if the correct number of words are entered.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`split.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) you have the number of words that you have in your array, so, you can make a condition. Like this:

```
do{
  //do stuff
}while(split.length != 3);
```